# Simperium JS login fail

Tags: javascript, authentication, simperium

I'm a newbie to Simperium and using the Javascript API.

I did get an access token using authorize but was then getting the 'auth' error when creating a new Simperium(...) so I tried getting a new token and this fails, returning error codes 400 or 401.

This is my code where KEY is the api key, ID is the application id, and USER and PASS are my username and password...

Authorization:

```
var url,request,response,json,token,auth;
url="https://auth.simperium.com/1/"+appID+"/authorize/";
request=new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(request.readyState===4) {
        if(request.status===200) {
            response=request.responseText;
            console.log('response: '+response);
            if(response.length>0) {
                json=JSON.parse(response);
                token=json.access_token;
                ...
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('ERROR');
            return null;
        }
    }
};
request.open("POST",url,true);
request.setRequestHeader("X-Simperium-API-Key",'"'+KEY+'"');
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
auth='{"username": "'+USER+'", "password": "'+PASS+'"}';
request.send(auth);
```

This fails with 400 or 401!

When I had an ACCESS_TOKEN:

```
var options="{token: '"+ACCESS_TOKEN+"'}";
var simperium=new Simperium(ID,options);
var bucket=simperium.bucket('ledger');
bucket.on('notify',function(id,data) {
    console.log("transaction updated: "+data);
    ...
});
bucket.on("error", function(error) {
    console.log("Simperium error : "+error);
    if (error == "auth") {
        console.log("auth error, need to reauthenticate and get new access token")
        ...
    }
});
bucket.start();
```

This resulted in the "auth" error.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things, for setting the request header on the API key, you shouldn't need the extra quotes around the api key, unless you're rendering this from a template. If your key was abcdefg, it should look like:

```
request.setRequestHeader("X-Simperium-API-Key","abcdefg");
```

Once you have an access token, when setting the options object, you should pass an object instead of a string:

```
var options={token: "ACCESS_TOKEN"};
```